# How to send variables from Jenkins so that the Postman environment can take them?

Tags: json, jenkins, continuous-integration, postman, jenkins-groovy

Currently I have an environment variable called URL, where I add the url that I need to use for each EndPoint that I have, however, I would like to know if it is possible to change this environment variable from Jenkins to indicate another url, for example wanting to work in environments already be it QA, DEV, Production, etc. If this is possible, how can I send that information to my collection (json) of environment variables?

This is my current JenkinsFile

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Running tests') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing'
                sh "newman run postman_collection.json -e .postman_environment.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered this on the Postman community post you raised earlier. 

Comment: Yes, I appreciate it, I responded to you in the Postman community too... Jajajaja...

Comment: Added the same answer so we can close this out 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either `--global-var` or `--env-var` to pass data from Jenkins into the Collection.

If the `{{foo}}` global variable were used in the Collection, it would resolve it to the `bar` value.

```
--global-var "foo=bar"
```

For your Jenkins example, you would need something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Running tests') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing'
                sh "newman run postman_collection.json -e .postman_environment.json --env-var 'variableName=$JENKINS_VARIABLE'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```